# Firebase dictionary return nil when clearly has Data

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my database structure:

```
orders_Placed {
  orderID {"date":...etc}
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve all orders, but the `dictionary.value` is nil although the dictionary when printed clearly contains data.

**Code:**

```
ref.child("orders_Placed").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    if let tes = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        print("snapshot dictionarty is snapshot \(tes.reversed())")
        for t in tes {
            print("\nsnapshot dictionarty name snapshot \(t.value["date"])") //*1

            print("\nsnapshot dictionarty name key T IS \(t)") //*2
        }}
```

**Output:**

```
snapshot dictionarty name snapshot nil //*1

snapshot dictionarty name key T IS ("date", 1479580695307) //*2 clearly has data but for some reason returns nil?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop that you used, `t` is actually a tuple of type `(key: String, value: AnyObject)`. To access the actual `key` or `value`, you simply have to do `t.key` or `t.value` respectively. No need to pass the string `key` to it anymore since `t` isn't a dictionary.

```
for t in tes
{
  var currentDateKey = t.key // the key associated to the date
  var currentDate = t.value // extracts the exact value
}
```

Comment: ohh, do you know why is it a tuple and not a dictionary? what confuses me is i'm using this code in a different place (before i restructured the database) and it returned a dictionary, which is alot easier since it allows me to extract all the data in one loop instead of this.

Comment: Its a tuple because you're iterating over a dictionary.. Its like when you have an array of integers.. Iterating over it gives you the actual integers.. When you iterate over a dictionary; since its a key/value pairing, it consists of two attributes which are best represented as a tuple.. If you want to access it as a dictionary then get rid of the for loop.. I posted an answer about this --> https://stack overflow.com/a/39862631

Comment: thank you emil, you really saved me hours of headache.